# How to show or hide image in HTML

Tags: html, image

In the following HTML/JS code, if I enter a valid e-mail id a command button and a tick mark should appear. But command button works fine. Tick mark is not appearing. Any one please help.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<form id="signUpForm">
  <input type="email" id="emailField" required>
  <button id="okButton" style="display:none">OK</button>
  <img id "img1" src="valid.jpg" width=100px style="display:none"/>

</form>

<script>
const signUpForm = document.getElementById('signUpForm');
const emailField = document.getElementById('emailField');
const flag1 = document.getElementById('okButton');
const img1 = document.getElementById('img1');

emailField.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
  isValidEmail = emailField.checkValidity();

  if ( isValidEmail ) {
        flag1.style="display:inline";
        img1.style="display:block"";
  } else {    
        flag1.style="display:none";
        img1.style="display:none";
 }
});

okButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  signUpForm.submit();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes which break the script flow in your code

1. No "=" for id assignment of image tag

   <img id "img1" src="valid.jpg" width=100px style="display:none"/>
2. Redundant double quote at the end of instruction

   img1.style="display:block"";

If you correct them all, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<form id="signUpForm">
  <input type="email" id="emailField" required>
  <button id="okButton" style="display:none">OK</button>
  <!-- fixed: id "img1" -> id="img1", width=100px -> width="100px" -->
  <img id="img1" src="valid.jpg" width="100px" style="display:none"/>

</form>

<script>
const signUpForm = document.getElementById('signUpForm');
const emailField = document.getElementById('emailField');
const flag1 = document.getElementById('okButton');
const img1 = document.getElementById('img1');

emailField.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
  isValidEmail = emailField.checkValidity();

  if ( isValidEmail ) {
        flag1.style="display:inline";
        img1.style="display:block"; //removed 3rd double quote
  } else {    
        flag1.style="display:none";
        img1.style="display:none";
 }
});

okButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  signUpForm.submit();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

````
<html>
</head>
<body>
<form id="signUpForm">
  <input type="email" id="emailField" required>
  <button id="okButton" style="display:none">OK</button>
  <!--You Missed Equlas to sign in id -->
  <img id ="img1" src="valid.jpg" width=100px style="display:none"/>

</form>

<script>
const signUpForm = document.getElementById('signUpForm');
const emailField = document.getElementById('emailField');
const flag1 = document.getElementById('okButton');
const img1 = document.getElementById('img1');

emailField.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
  isValidEmail = emailField.checkValidity();

  if ( isValidEmail ) {
        flag1.style="display:inline";
        img1.style="display:block";
  } else {    
        flag1.style="display:none";
        img1.style="display:none";
 }
});

okButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  signUpForm.submit();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>```
````